# How to pass clicked image value on php in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I want to if any one click on image than only clicked image sl number pass to php page. but i don't get any imge sl number. I am trying to find out the problem. but i can't please, any one help me. thanks. here is my code

```
                <?php
$query="select * from image_content order by sl";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);

for ($i=0; $i<$num; $i++)
{


    $sl=mysql_result($result, $i, "sl");
    $title=mysql_result($result, $i, "title");
    $image_name=mysql_result($result, $i, "image_name");



    echo"
        <div id='image_style'>

    <div id='upload_image'>
        <a class='picture_description' href='#' title='$title'>
        <img src='../download/$image_name' />
     <div align='center'>Title: $title</div>
    </a>
   </div>
<input type='hidden' class='picture_sl' name='picture_sl' value='$sl'/>
</div>";
}
?>
```

jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".picture_description").click(function() {

        var action = $("#form1").attr('action');
        var form_data = {
            picture_sl: $(".picture_sl").val(),
            is_ajax: 1
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: action,
            data: form_data,
            success: function(response)
            {

                        $("#div_1").html(response);

                }
        });

        return false;
    });

});
</script>
```

loaded php:

```
<?php

echo $picture_sl=$_POST['picture_sl'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your click handler you are selecting any input element with the class "picture_sl", not the one that was clicked.

You could use a data attribute on your anchor tag like this

```
<a class='picture_description' href='#' title='$title' data-picture='$sl'>
```

and then retrieve it with the jQuery data() method:

```
   $(".picture_description").click(function() {

    var action = $("#form1").attr('action');
    var form_data = {
        picture_sl: $(this).data('picture'),
        is_ajax: 1
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be indexing the images and descriptions HTML meaning that they will all have the following output `<input type='hidden' class='picture_sl' name='picture_sl' value='X'/>`. What you want them to look like is `<input type='hidden' class='picture_sX' name='picture_sX' value='X'/>`. To accomplish this, simply update your code to the following

```
<?php
$query="select * from image_content order by sl";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);

for ($i=0; $i<$num; $i++) {

  $sl=mysql_result($result, $i, "sl");
  $title=mysql_result($result, $i, "title");
  $image_name=mysql_result($result, $i, "image_name");

  echo"
  <div class='image_style'>
    <div class='upload_image'>
      <a class='picture_description' href='#' title='$title'>
        <img src='../download/$image_name' />
        <div align='center'>Title: $title</div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <input type='hidden' class='picture_s".$i."' name='picture_s".$i."' value='".$sl."'/>
  </div>";
}
?>
```

One thing I did change in your code was the `<div id='image_style'>` and `<div id='upload_image'>` simply because you should not have multiple identical IDs in a html page.

And here's the JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".test").click(function () {
    $(event.target).children('div').each(function(){
      var action = $("#form1").attr('action');
      var form_data = {
        picture_sl: $(this).attr('value'),
        is_ajax: 1
      });

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: action,
        data: form_data,
        success: function(response) {
          $("#div_1").html(response);
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for you kind response, can you tell me how can pass the <input type='hidden' class='picture_s".$i."' name='picture_s".$i."' value='".$sl."'/> following input value on loaded php file

Comment: Hi, I'll update my answer shortly with the updated JavaScript.